# Joint p.d.f. of n i.i.d. variables

Tags: statistics

I have searched for quite a bit on the Internet and I wonder
whether I can double check with you my concept about the joint p.d.f. in terms of the n variables i.i.d to a Beta distribution.

For example, I let the p.d.f. of X as

$f_x(x)=\theta x^{(\theta-1)}, 0<x<1$

Can I write down the joint p.d.f. of (X1,X2,...,Xn) as
$f_x(x1,x2,...,x_n)=\theta^n(x_1x_2...x_n)^{\theta-1}$
?

I am confused about the joint p.d.f. concept if I am only given the p.d.f.
of X.

Thank you very much for reading and any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the joint PDF of independent variables is the product of the PDFs of the individual variables. Note, independence is crucial here.

So we have $$ f_{X_1,\ldots, X_n}(x_1,\ldots x_n) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)\ldots f_{X_n}(x_n).$$ Since they are also identically distributed, with the distribution $f_X(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1},$ we have $$ f_{X_1,\ldots, X_n}(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \theta x_1^{\theta-1}\theta x_2^{\theta-1}\ldots \theta x_n^{\theta-1} = \theta^n (x_1x_2\ldots x_n)^{\theta-1}$$

Comment: May I also ask that, if I take log for the joint p.d.f., my answer would be $n*log(\theta)+(\theta-1)log(x_1x_2...x_n)$, any chance I can better simplify this? Thank you!

Comment: @Chen Nope, that looks good